# Remove extra index in a dataframe

Tags: python

I would like to remove the extra index called service_type_id that I have not included in my code but it just appear without any reason. I am using Python.

My code is

```
data_tr = data.groupby(['transaction_id', 'service_type']).sum().unstack().reset_index().fillna(0).set_index('transaction_id')
```

The output is this table with extra index:
[image]

I believe it is something to do with the groupby and unstack. Kindly highlight to me why there will be extra index and what should be my code be.

The dataset
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XZVfXbgpV0l3Oewgh09Vw5lVCchK0SEh/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope [pandas.DataFrame.droplevel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) can do the job for you query

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Dataset - Transaction.csv')
data_tr = df.groupby(['transaction_id', 'service_type']).sum().unstack().reset_index().fillna(0).set_index('transaction_id').droplevel(0,1)
data_tr.head(2)
```

**Output**

[image]

`df.groupby(['transaction_id', 'service_type']).sum()` takes the sum of numerical field `service_type_id`

```
data_tr = df.groupby(['transaction_id', 'service_type']).sum().unstack()
print(data_tr.columns)

MultiIndex([('service_type_id',                 '3 Phase Wiring'),
            ('service_type_id',                   'AV Equipment')
            ...
            ('service_type_id',                   'Yoga Lessons'),
            ('service_type_id',                  'Zumba Classes')],
           names=[None, 'service_type'], length=188)
#print(data_tr.info())
```

Initially there was only one column (`service_type_id`) and two indexes `transaction_id, service_type`, After you unstack service_type becomes column like tuples (Multindex) where each service type have value of service_type_id. `droplevel(0,1)` will convert your dataframe from Multindex to single Index as follows

```
print(data_tr.columns)
Index(['3 Phase Wiring', ......,'Zumba Classes'],
      dtype='object', name='service_type', length=188)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. @Rinshan Kolayil
The index service_type_id is not a column in the original dataset. I am still not understand how it come from. Unstack the non-numerical column, service_type, will generate a new column/index and will this change the value on summing the value of the number of service_type cointain for each transaction_id, (['transaction_id', 'service_type']) during the groupby process?

Comment: I can see there was a column `service_type_id`  with numercal values in your dataframe. Please try `print(df.columns)` before group by and you check the columns. After unstack it will not change the values. After unstack `service_type` converted to columns

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation. For the Edit part, the NaN value is fill with zero and not being removed during the groupby of transaction_id, am I right?

May I know what does the 0 refer to in the following code? 
df2.loc[0,"transaction_id"] = np.NAN

Comment: Yes NaN values filled with zeros with fillna(0) and df2.loc[0,"transaction_id"] refers to transaction_id of first row. In your case fillna works after group by. Please do some experiments with first 5 rows for better understanding

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I have another question in Stack overflow. Do you mind to help me as well? The link is below.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68891426/apriori-algorithm-not-showing-result

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to make a pivot table of `transaction_id` and `service_type`, using `service_type_id` as value. The reason you are getting the extra index, is because your `sum` generates a sum for every (numerical) column.

For insight, try to execute just

```
data.groupby(['transaction_id', 'service_type']).sum()
```

Since the data uses the label `service_type_id`, I assume the `sum` actually only serves the purpose of getting the id value out. A cleaner way to get the desired result is usig a `pivot`

```
data_tr = data[['transaction_id'
       , 'service_type'
       , 'service_type_id']
   ].pivot(index = 'transaction_id'
              , columns= 'service_type'
              , values = 'service_type_id'
   ).fillna(0)
```

Depending on how you like your data structure, you can follow up with a `.reset_index()`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, the new index, service_type_id, is not available from the original dataset. I do not want it to appear so I should not include it in my code right?